# Existe alguma forma de ler um arquivo XLS e manipulá-lo em Python?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Existe alguma forma de ler um arquivo XLS e manipulá-lo em Python? Alguma biblioteca permite isso?

Comment: Existem varias formas, por exemplo https://blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2014/06/16/reading-excel-with-python-xlrd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import xlrd

def xlread(arq_xls):
    """
    Gerador que le arquivo .xls
    """

    # Abre o arquivo
    xls = xlrd.open_workbook(arq_xls)
    # Pega a primeira planilha do arquivo
    plan = xls.sheets()[0]

    # Para i de zero ao numero de linhas da planilha
    for i in xrange(plan.nrows):
        # Le os valores nas linhas da planilha
        yield plan.row_values(i)

for linha in xlread('test.xls'):
    print (linha)
```

pip install xlrd

Comment: Acho que você deveria adicionar mais detalhes às suas respostas. Percebo que algumas respostas estão sendo publicadas somente com código.  Seria interessante por exemplo, você explicar para que serve o trecho `plan = xls.sheets()[0]`.